# Displaying next array element using setTimeout() method

Tags: arrays, function, settimeout

How come my paragraph doesn't display third array element after delay? Should I use *clearTimeout()*?

```js
document.getElementById("helloText").innerHTML = combined[0];
setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById("helloText").innerHTML = combined[1]; }, 1000);
setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById("helloText").innerHTML = combined[2]; }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of your setTimeout() functions are being called after 1 second, so your text is changing after the same time delay.

That's why you're only seeing one of your array elements, instead of both.

Try changing the second setTimeout from a delay of 1000 to 2000.

If they are both 1000, you'll only see one of them.

```js
    var combined = ["1. dog", "2. cat", "3. lizard"]
    
    document.getElementById("helloText").innerHTML = combined[0];
    
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("helloText").innerHTML = combined[1];
    }, 1000);
    
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("helloText").innerHTML = combined[2];
    }, 2000);
```

```html
<div id="helloText">hi</div>
```